# Как вивести дополнительную информацию в django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django

Помогите найти информацию, как сделать чтобы здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class Varianti(models.Model):
labaratory = models.ForeignKey(Labaratory, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
variant_number = models.CharField('Номер варіанта', max_length = 2)
lab_price = models.CharField('Ціна роботи (грн.)', max_length = 3)

def __str__(self):
    return self.labaratory.title

class Meta():
    verbose_name = "Варіант"
    verbose_name_plural = "Варіанти"
```

также выводилось номер варианта и цена.Потому что сейчас выводится только название лабораторной (сильно не ругайте изучаю DJANGO второй день.

Comment: пожалуйста, более подробно опишите ваш вопрос и уточните что именно вы хотите достигнуть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете подредактировать строковое представление модели. К примеру:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.labaratory.title} {self.variant_number} {self.lab_price}'
```

Также рекомендую в поле lab_price использовать `models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)`([доп. инфа](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield))
тогда можно будет со значением из этого поля работать как с числом и цена будет всегда корректной до копейки

Comment: а почему не `list_display_fields`?